# recursive way to go through a nested list and remove all of a select value

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to remove all empty lists from a nested list recursively.

```
def listcleaner(lst):
   if isinstance(lst[0], int):
      return listcleaner(lst[1:])


   if isinstance(lst[0], list):
     if len(lst[0]) == []:
        lst[0].remove([])
        return listcleaner(lst)
     return listcleaner(lst[0])
   return lst
```

and what I'd like the function to do is

```
>>> a = listcleaner([1, [], [2, []], 5])
>>> print(a)
[1, [2], 5]
```

Comment: What is problem with your current code?

Comment: >>> listcleaner([1, [2, []], []])
      itll run through and refer me back to multiple lines and then say list index out of range

Comment: This is not an appropriate question. You can't be biased with a technique. It's programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this meets your criterion of being recursive:

```
def listcleaner(lst, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return lst
    if not lst:
        return result
    head = listcleaner(lst[0])
    if head != []:
        result.append(head)
    return listcleaner(lst[1:], result)
```

Test:

```
>>> listcleaner([])
[]
>>> listcleaner([1, [], [2, []], 5])
[1, [2], 5]
>>> listcleaner([1, [], [2, [], [[], [], 3]], 5])
[1, [2, [3]], 5]
```

**Caveat**: I don't know what you want to do with nested cases like `[[[]]]`. On one interpretation of "remove all empty lists", since only the innermost list is empty, the function should just remove that and return `[[]]`. Another interpretation is that we should keep going until no empty list is left, and return `[]`. My solution does the latter. (To be honest, haven't found a way to do the former ...)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you return, you are quitting the function.  Here is the updated code:

```
def listcleaner(lst):
    if not lst:   # If list is empty
        return [] # Go no further
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        if lst[0]: # If the list has something in it, we want to run listcleaner() on it.
            return [listcleaner(lst[0])] + listcleaner(lst[1:])
        else: # Otherwise, just skip that list
            return listcleaner(lst[1:])
    else:
        return [lst[0]] + listcleaner(lst[1:]) # If it is not a list, return it unchanged plus listcleaner() on the rest.

a = listcleaner([1, [], [2, []], 5]) 
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, [2], 5]
```

Comment: this is not recursive

Comment: It depends on how far I have to go in order for it to count as recursive.  If you read through the whole code, you will see that I *do* call `listcleaner()` again to get sub-lists cleaned up.

Comment: It cannot use for or while loops. only if statements.

Comment: @YousufMadi: Is it okay if `listcleaner()` returns `[1, 2, 5]`?  I've written something that will do that, but I am still working on keeping the `2` as a list.

Comment: @YousufMadi: I just updated my answer.  It has no `for` or `while` loops; just `if` statements.

Comment: @zondo thank you! would it be possible for you to edit and put logical comments. I promise this isnt a homework question Im just not completely understanding whats happening here.

Comment: @YousufMadi: I just added the comments.  If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def listcleaner(lst):
    result = []
    for l in lst:
        if type(l) == list and len(l) > 0:
            result.append(listcleaner(l))
        elif type(l) != list:
            result.append(l)
    return result
```

Comment: Comparing `type(some_object)` to a type is not recommended.  Instances of sub-classes would still return False.  You should use `isinstance()` instead.  See my answer.

Comment: Yeah but this isnt recursive, Im trying to do this recursively

Comment: Do you see the `result.append(listcleaner(l))` line?

Comment: Yeah sorry the requirements say that I cannot use for loops or while loops though

Comment: It looks like we are really in the same boat.

Comment: You might want to add those requirements (no loops) to your question. At any level of the list structure you will need to iterate through the elements at that level.  For a true recursive pathway see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563271/recursively-going-through-a-list-python

Answer (score 0):

```
def listcleaner(lst):
   n=len(lst)
   i=0
   while i < n :
        if isinstance(lst[i],list):
            if len(lst[i])==0:
                del lst[i]
                n=len(lst)
            else: 
                listcleaner(lst[i])
                i=i+1
        else:
            i=i+1
   return lst


a= listcleaner([1, [], [2, []], 5])
b= listcleaner([1,[],[2,[],[[],[],3]],5])
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[1, [2], 5]
[1, [2, [3]], 5]
```